# Exibir consulta de Tabelas Relacionadas Mysql

Tags: mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados

encontrei algumas resposta sobre o assunto, porem ainda me surgiu algumas duvidas, vou tentar ser mais claro possivel.
Meu Exemplo de Banco.
tenho as seguintes Tabelas

### Tabela

- Cliente>  id | nome| pedido
- cliente_sistema> id_cliente | id_sistema (extrangeira)
- Sistema > id | id_sist | versao
- Servico > id_sist | id_num | id_serie (Chave extrangeira)
- Numero> id | tipo | lic
- Serie > id | nserie | chave

No modelo acima tenho, o CLIENTE com a ID chave primaria nome e pedido(dados) como segue as outras tabelas, com exceção das cliente_sistema e Servico, relacionada como extrangeira.

O que estou tantando é o seguinte, no cadastro do cliente ele terá mais de uma opção de serviço, e no serviço terá um tipo e no tipo, tenho um numero de serie, ao realizar a consulta trazer todos os servico e serie do cliente dentro da tabela.

tenho que usar a INNER JOIN para esse regra.

Tenho o modelo de Banco no MySQL Workbench

Agradeço quem puder clarear minha ideia

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida?

Comment: Você já respondeu sua pergunta, vai precisar usar joins, agora você precisa ver a necessidade/estrutura e formular a query de forma que te atenda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os `JOINs`ficariam assim:

```
SELECT * FROM cliente c
JOIN cliente_sistema cs ON cs.id_cliente = c.id
JOIN sistema st ON st.id = cd.id_sistema
JOIN servico sv ON sv.id_sist = st.id
JOIN numero n ON n.id = sv.id_num
JOIN serie sr ON sr.id = sv.id_serie;
```

Basta colocar no `SELECT` os campos que você precisa.